# Track key press and key release on WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a way to track key press and release actions on WPF?

This is what I've tried so far, but what I'm finding is that the `_upDownKeyIsPressed` is only set to false if I press another key - not when the up or down key is released

```
    private void KeyUpPress(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            _upDownKeyIsPressed = true;
            Console.WriteLine(_upDownKeyIsPressed.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void KeyDownPress(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            _upDownKeyIsPressed = false;
            Console.WriteLine(_upDownKeyIsPressed.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void PlotListView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyUpPress(e);
    }

    private void PlotListView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyDownPress(e);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should put it to `true` on KeyDown and to `false` on KeyUp.

Comment: I added a real answer to the problem. Did it help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try what I said in comment. I think about something like this :

```
    private void PlotListView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TrackUpDownKeyPress(e, false);
    }

    private void PlotListView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TrackUpDownKeyPress(e, true);
    }

    private void TrackUpDownKeyPress(KeyEventArgs e, bool isPressed)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
            _upDownKeyIsPressed = isPressed;
    }
```

If you want more info about the difference between keyUp and keyDown, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871383/1248177).