# What can be overriding the prevent default ? Pressing enter to click target submits the form but doesn't click (javascript/Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events

I have a simple code...

```
   document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e)
    {
           if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(e.target).trigger("click");
            }
});
```

this is working fine with keycode 32 (space), but not for keycode 13 (enter) where it always submits the form. 
I tried adding prevent default after reading answers to some similar questions, but it doesnt solve the issue. the form is submitted anyways after pressing enter.I am looking after a solution which can be written in the script tag; since I do not want to disturb the form tags. 
Also, this script(without the prevent default) was working fine till some days ago.

Comment: Use `onsubmit` event of the form to prevent submit

Comment: I'm not really sure how the onsubmit is programmed, coz its not on the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Su-J, if you are using an `input` field to submit, then you can add an attribute somewhere like this: `<input type="submit" onsubmit="return false;"/>`. Or you can add it to the `<form>` tag `<form type="post" onsubmit="return false;"/>`

Edit:
I'd also try `keypress` instead. 
KeyPress is raised for character keys (unlike KeyDown and KeyUp, which are also raised for noncharacter keys) while the key is pressed. This is a "higher-level" event than either KeyDown or KeyUp, and as such, different data is available in the EventArgs.

See more from answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871383/difference-between-the-keydown-event-keypress-event-and-keyup-event-in-visual-s)

Comment: Thanks, but I did a little edit after looking at your answer. I am not sure of how the form is programmed, since there are no form tags in the html

Comment: In the past I've had better success with `keypress`. I definitely recommend replacing `keydown` with `keypress` as well. Options are limited without access to the DOM element submitting the form.

Comment: nope. Thats not working. Additionally, prevent default works for the space key but not for enter.